# Django image:this field is required

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to send a form with an image, I select the image but I always get: "this field is required" when I send the form.
here is my code:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Picture(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.ImageField()
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.user', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='pictures')
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class PictureForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    caption = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Picture
from .forms import PictureForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def pictures_view(request):
    pictures = Picture.objects.all()
    context = {'pictures': pictures}
    return render(request, 'pictures/pictures.html', context)

def picture_form_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PictureForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            clean_data = form.cleaned_data()
            Picture.objects.create(clean_data)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = PictureForm()

    return render(request, 'pictures/picture_form.html', {'form': form})
```

HTML:

```
{% extends 'pictures/base.html' %}
{% block title %}publish{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <form class="form" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

And a Little question, how can I complete the field author automaticly with the actual user?

Answer (score 0):

first of all `ImageField` in model takes one compulsory argument `upload_to` so in your models

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    ###
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload/to/path')
    ###
```

now in your view

```
def picture_form_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PictureForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            clean_data = form.cleaned_data()
            Picture.objects.create(**clean_data)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = PictureForm()

    return render(request, 'pictures/picture_form.html', {'form': form})
```

and to save current logged in user as default override `form_valid()`
method in Form class like

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have done what yo have said me but the error continues

Comment: Can you please post the traceback ?

Comment: complete traceback ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t understand the question. The problema is that I don´t get any error in the code. All work but appear 'this field is required' in the template, like If the field was empty.

Comment: when you receive an error, django gives you a traceback(log) on your console

Comment: Yes, but I don´t recive any error, I just can´t upload the image.

Comment: I complet the fields but when i upload the form I get that the image isn´t selected.

Comment: try printing request.FILES, and see if your file is coming through

Comment: I get <MultiValueDict: {}> so the image don´t come through but I don´t know why.

Comment: I have found the problem, I had to write 'enctype="multipart/form-data" ' in the <form>.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `enctype` to `"multipart/form-data"` in the form tag.

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
  
input here ...  
  
</form>
```